# User Information on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and when I have an user logged in using forms authenticaion, I would like to keep some information about this user. The HttpContext User object, implemented from IPrincipal has some properties, but I would like to add some more, so that I could get these on my actions and views. What's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.bradygaster.com/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, but I found out this blog post that helped me with this issue: http://www.creatingsoftware.net/2007/11/aspnet-20-forms-authentication-keeping.html

Answer (score 0):

We have used this in the past to store additional information about the user in the Forms Authentication cookie:  http://formsauthext.codeplex.com/

Seems to work fairly well and prevents a few database hits since some basic information is available from the cookie.  Also, going this route prevents issues around sessions (expiring, app recycling, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Membership, Role or Profile providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to persist information about your users.